# Attempted relative imports beyond top-level package?

Tags: python

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
game/
    graphics/
          __init__.py
          render.py
    sound/
         __init__.py
         echo.py
    __init__.py
```

and my `render.py` reads `from ..sound.echo import echo_test`, 
but every time I run it it says `Attempted relative imports beyond top-level package`.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py?rq=1

Comment: @cricket   to be candid, i studied python only for 2 days and can get any of the comments in your link..!! i'm using pycharm, and when i typed 'from game.sound.echo', it worked well. i don't get the differene between relative importing and this.

Comment: Well, if you studied for only two days, I might suggest to perhaps start at the tutorial. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a relative import?

Can you use `from game.sound.echo import echo_test`?

Though, since you haven't shown the exact stacktrace, the error could be coming from `echo.py`. An attempted "import beyond top-level package" is self-explanatory, though.

[PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) could be worth a read

Comment: Simplest solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are trying the following, or something similar: `python render.py`

But this is treating render.py as a script and not a component of a package.  If you write an external script, where you
`import render`, and then test `render` functions, the imports should work fine.

You may want to have a look at [Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/)